# Proof that cycle doesn't exist

Tags: graph-theory

There are vertices $u$ and $v$ in a graph so that every path from $u$ to $v$ includes the edge $e$. I need to prove that there isn't a cycle that includes the edge $e$. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Hint. How would you connect the two ends of $e$ to  complete a cycle that uses $e$?

Answer (score 1):

If there was a cycle containing edge $e$, then instead of using $e$ to get from $u$ to $v$, you could always go around the rest of the cycle besides $e$ instead.  This would contradict the idea that you must use $e$ to get from $u$ to $v$.